# base repository is undefined

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

in NestJs I implement the standard repository pattern.

I have my repository interface:

```
import { CreateUserDto } from '../dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from '../dto/update-user.dto';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';

export interface IUserRepository {
  findAll(): Promise<User[]>;
  findById(id: number): Promise<User | undefined>;
  addEntity(user: CreateUserDto): Promise<User>;
  updateEntity(
    id: number,
    updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto,
  ): Promise<User | undefined>;
  deleteEntity(id: number): Promise<boolean>;
}

export const IUserRepository = Symbol('IUserRepository');
```

Then I have the implementation, which extends the base repository from TypeORM:

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { IUserRepository } from './interfaces/repository.interface';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';

export class UserRepository
  extends Repository<User>
  implements IUserRepository
{
  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.find();
  }

  async findById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return this.findOneBy({ id: id });
  }

  async addEntity(user: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const newUser = this.create(user);
    return this.save(newUser);
  }

  async updateEntity(
    id: number,
    updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto,
  ): Promise<User | undefined> {
    const user = await this.findById(id);
    if (!user) return undefined;

    Object.assign(user, updateUserDto);
    return this.save(user);
  }

  async deleteEntity(id: number): Promise<boolean> {
    const result = await this.delete(id);
    return result.affected > 0;
  }
}
```

The service looks like this:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';
import { IUserRepository } from './interfaces/repository.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(IUserRepository) private readonly userRepository: IUserRepository,
  ) {}

  async findAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
  }

  async findUserById(id: number): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.userRepository.findById(id);
  }

  async createUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository.addEntity(createUserDto);
  }

  async updateUser(
    id: number,
    updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto,
  ): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.userRepository.updateEntity(id, updateUserDto);
  }

  async deleteUser(id: number): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.userRepository.deleteEntity(id);
  }
}
```

And the Users module looks like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { UserService } from './users.service';
import { UserController } from './users.controller';
import { UserRepository } from './users.repository';
import { IUserRepository } from './interfaces/repository.interface';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [
    UserService,
    { provide: IUserRepository, useClass: UserRepository },
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

It compiles without any error. But if I hit the `create` method in the controller, I get the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')`, which belongs to this line: `const newUser = this.create(user);`

On the net, there are github and other posts about this. I have tried all the possible solutions described there, but the error remains.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question is fun.

To solve this issue, I had to inject the data source like this:

```
constructor(
    @InjectDataSource()
    private dataSource: DataSource,
  ) {
    super(User, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }
```